# $$var (in php) Equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, var

I have a variable `var commision_1 = 2000 ;var commision_2 = 4000;` and a function:

```
function updateCommission(period){
    $("input:text[name='commission']").val('commision_'+period);
}
```

I would like if period is 1 then the value of the textbox be 2000;
I know I can use arrays, but I am working on someone else's code, is there a way around it
just like in php how I would have written `$x = 'commision_' .$period; echo $$x;`

Comment: this should be array or object instead

Comment: @RoyalBg *'I know I can use arrays, but I am working on someone else's code'*

Comment: @George So the problem should be fixed, not danced around.

Comment: They still can be pushed into an array. Someone else's (messy) code is not a reason to write more mess :)

Comment: @RoyalBg & Niet, Agree with the both of you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use square bracket notation to get variable variables.

Provided these variables are defined in the window scope:

```
function updateCommission(period){
    $("input:text[name='commission']").val(window['commision_' + period]);
}
```

Having said that, defining numbered variables (*all the way up to 2000..!?*) isn't a good idea. An array was born to serve this purpose. My best answer would be to request these variables be re-written as an array, but I appreciate this is often easier said than done.

Answer (score 1):

```
var commission_1 = 2000, commission_2 = 4000;
var name = 'commission_1';
console.log(window[name]);
```

Comment: Completely fails if you are inside a function. -1